# Rails 2.3.8 I18n::UnknownFileType the file type yml is not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.8.7

i have an old rails project here running rails 2.3.8 and ruby 1.8.7 with rvm.

when i'm running `rake -T` or another rake task it will fail with

> I18n::UnknownFileType: can not load translations from /home/project/trunk/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml, the file type yml is not known

running some YAML in the console, will work.

i found some solutions for rails 3 and ruby 1.9.3 ([Rails 3: 'The file type yml is not known' when trying to access basic _form.html.erb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234007/rails-3-the-file-type-yml-is-not-known-when-trying-to-access-basic-form-html)) and rails 2.3 with ruby 2 ([Rails legacy app and Ruby 2 error: can not load translations from the file type yml is not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035094/rails-legacy-app-and-ruby-2-error-can-not-load-translations-from-the-file-type)) but didnt help.

my Gems used in this project:

```
actionmailer (2.3.18)
actionpack (2.3.18)
activerecord (2.3.18)
activeresource (2.3.18)
activesupport (2.3.18)
afm (0.2.2)
Ascii85 (1.0.2)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
color (1.8)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
hashery (2.1.1)
iconv (1.0.4)
little-plugger (1.1.4)
logging (2.0.0, 1.8.2)
multi_json (1.11.2)
mysql (2.9.1)
pdf-core (0.6.0)
pdf-reader (1.3.3)
pdf-writer (1.1.8)
prawn (2.0.2, 0.12.0)
rack (1.1.6)
rails (2.3.18)
rake (10.4.2, 10.1.1)
ruby-rc4 (0.1.5)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
transaction-simple (1.4.0.2)
ttfunk (1.4.0, 1.0.3)
```

`script/console` and `script/server` running fine.

i have to use ruby 1.8.7 and cannot update. upgrade to rails 3 is'nt possible in month's :)

do you have some idea's to get the rake tasks running?

best 
robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution:

there was several problems:

1. `rake (10.4.2, 10.1.1)` now just using rake 10.1.1
2. `logging (2.0.0, 1.8.2)` now just using logging 1.8.2
3. (after testing) had to replace `rdoctask` with `task` in `Rakefile`

now `rake -T` works fine